# Shared xib file between parent and child uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, inheritance, xib

I want to create a generic uitableviewcell which i'll customize by overriding some methods.

There's my parent **UITableViewCell** : **IconTitleGenericTableViewCell**

I've designed my cell in a xib file : **IconTitleGenericTableViewCell.xib**

Now i've subclassed my parent cell with this child class : **MyTitleCell**

What i want is **MyTitleCell** to instantiate the designated xib file from it's parent.

I've tried to use

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:key bundle:bundle];
[tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

But the cell return in by

```
 MyTitleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is an ***IconTitleGenericTableViewCell*** and not ***MyTitleCell***.

How can i managed to get the same view and outlets link **without any xib duplication** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a nib with a regular `UIView` in it with the File's owner as your `IconTitleGenericTableViewCell` and in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` load the view from the nib and add it to the cell's content view.

Then register your cells using `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`. Any subclass you register will come out as the correct class when dequeued and have the view from the nib added to it's content view.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. Your solution does work, but by doing this, y loose the interaction with the tableview. For exemple i never go through - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated.

I have to disable userInteraction on the xib but i won't be able to interact with uitableviewcell having UIButton or UISwitch

Answer (score 0):

Make a nib file independent UIView, make all outlet connections to FileOwner and load your cell using that function:

```
- (instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier { {
    return [super initWithNibName:@"YourXibName" bundle:nil]);
}
```

Comment: This "[super initWithNibName:@"YourXibName" bundle:nil]" is a not known method for UITableViewCell